# Mapping JSON Response into Object with JAX-RS and JAXB

Tags: java, jaxb, jax-rs, cxf

I'm trying to map the response I get from a remote service into an object. For the client I'm using JAX-RS annotated interface:

```
@GET
@Path("/content/example.data")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Cacheable("my-data")
Items getInfo(
        @PathParam("country") String country,
        @PathParam("language") String language);
```

The response comes in this format, as a JSON list of objects:

```
[
  {
    "code": "01",
    "name": "Item1",
    "description": "Description for item1",
    "show": true
  },
  {
    "code": "02",
    "name": "Item2",
    "description": "Description for item2",
    "show": true
  }
]
```

And the class I'm trying to map into is:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Items {

    @XmlElementWrapper
    List<Item> items;

    public List<Item> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public void setItems(List<Item> items) {
        this.items = items;
    }

}


@XmlRootElement
public class Item {

    @XmlElement(name = "code")
    private String code;
    @XmlElement(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @XmlElement(name = "description")
    private String description;
    @XmlElement(name = "show")
    private Boolean show;

    public Item(){

    }

    //...getters/setters
}
```

It always returns an Items instance with an empty list of items. Any ideas?

**UPDATE**

Changing it to:

```
List<Item> getInfo(
            @PathParam("country") String country,
            @PathParam("language") String language);
```

returns `ArrayList<ElementNSImpl>` where I can see the properties by navigating through the nodes. But it doesn't map it to the Item class.

I changed the response to be only an object instead of an array on the server and changed the interface to:

```
Item getInfo(
            @PathParam("country") String country,
            @PathParam("language") String language);
```

and it maps the object perfectly, so the problem must be when mapping objects inside a list.

Comment: have you configured JSON parser in Jersey?

Comment: Yes, I'm using org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider

Comment: For update: Yes, it's one of the solutions if you have access to the server. But did you try an array Item[]?

Comment: Neither List<Item> or Item[] worked. List<Items> returns a list with the right amount of elements, but the Elements are not mapped into objects, they're plane jaxrs ElementNS objects. Items tries to map all the objects as one, and returns an error because it finds multiple occurrences of the same properties (obviously)

Comment: Are you implementing both the client and the server, then? Have you tried `@XmlType` instead of `@XmlRootElement` on `Item`? I think that the *JSON* you show looks like `List<Item>`, rather than a wrapper element at all, BTW. In which case, the question would be, what kind of non-simple cases can cause a mapping to `ElementNSImpl`. Also, these particular behaviors might be specific to CXF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Server returns an array of Item objects. Not an Items object with an "items" field. You've setup your conversion as though you receive this:

```
{
    "items": [
        {
            ...
        },
        {
            ...
        }
    ]
}
```

Here it's an object with the `items` field. Note, `{}` brackets mean an object, `[]` mean an array.

but you get this - just an array:

```
[    
    {
        ...
    },
    {
        ...
    }
]
```

So you need to convert it to a `List<Item>` or an array `Item[]` first (depends on what conversion your framework supports) and then set this list to the `Items` instance manually.

The issue is that the conversion framework can't understand that you want that array be in the `items` field (think of a case when there are two different List fields in the `Items` class - which one should it choose to convert into?).

Having received a list or a an array, set it to the `Items.items` manually.

```
// List<Item> itemsList - received and converted automatically.
Items items = new Items();
items.setItems(itemsList);
```

Comment: Sorry there was a typo in the class name, the first class is Items, the second one is Item. I tried changing it to return List<Items> but it returns null and, if I remove @Produces(JSON) then it returns a list of 2 items (good) with 2 Elements that haven't been mapped into Item

Comment: Not List<Items>, but List<Item>.

Comment: Sorry, that's what I meant, List<Item>. It doesn't allow me to edit it

Comment: Then try an array - Item[]. In any case you won't be able to convert it to Items at once, because you receive an array and not an object with the items field.